# jquery search box, clicking a link to prepopulate search field won't work

Tags: jquery, forms, search, onclick, submit

Okay, quick question!

http://jsfiddle.net/UYtz8/

If you type **orange** or **apple** into the search box, you see it hides away the one it isn't.

That works perfectly.

What I am trying to do is, if I click for example **orange**, I want it to populate that search box, and then do what it does when you naturally type orange..

Right now clicking **orange** will fill the search box, but it doesn't make the jquery work.

Any ideas or help?

**HTML**

```
Search: <input id = "searchbox" type = "text"/><br/>

<div class="track">
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<h3><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('searchbox').value='orange';">orange</a></h3>
</div>

<div class="track">
<h1>section 2</h1>
<h3><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('searchbox').value='apple';">apple</a></h3>
</div>​
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#searchbox").on("keydown keyup keypress change", function() {
var query = this.value.toLowerCase();
$(".track").each(function() {
    var cur = $(this);
    if(cur.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) == -1) {
        cur.hide("fast");
    }
    else {
        cur.show("fast");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: I personally don't really get what the goal is here.  If you give us more details about what you want to accomplish we might be able to help you better.

Comment: The goal is simply: I am trying to make it so if you click orange, it fills the searchbox field with the word orange, which it does correctly, but when it fill the searchbox field, it doesn't actually perform the jquery script I have on the page

Comment: where as, if you manually type in the word, orange, into the searchbox, you can see the jquery script work (it hides the .track div that does not contain the keyword you type in)

Comment: so I cant figure out how to make an anchor link work so that it fills the searchbox field, and yet still make the jquery script work.

Comment: Editing your question to "2QFC544444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444" won't make it go away, it will only attract nosy bastards like myself to come roll the edit back.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - indeed.  All this user's questions have received the same treatment, have flagged it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not executing your search logic when onclick event is fired. You're only assigning the value to search input field. Change your script into this:

```
function search(query){
    $(".track").each(function() {
        var cur = $(this);
        if(cur.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
            cur.hide("fast");
        }
        else {
            cur.show("fast");
        }
    });
}        

$("#searchbox").on("keydown keyup keypress change", function() {
    search($(this).val());
});

$(".track h3 a").on("click", function() {
    search($("#searchbox").val());
});
```

Comment: You are the man! Thank you! I am a little rusty, and knew there was something I had to do! thank you!